# Ruby on rails routing matching username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am sure there is a simple solution to this but I can't seem to find it.

I want to match the following dynamic username:

```
 /users/dymanicUsername
```

How would this look in routes.rb

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

allister,

To do that, just override to_param in your model. For instance :

```
#users.rb

def to_param
  self.username
end
```

You will soon bump into some problems :

- conflicts with existing routes. For instance, the username should not be 'new', got it ?
- for fetching you user in the controller, you should create a method (that's what I did, mayybe not the best solution) in your model like this self.find_for_controller(username)
- your username shall only contains url-enabled characters (forget accents, ponctuations etc...). A solution for this is to have a second attribute names `username_urlized`, that of course should be unique and not conflicting with other routes

And maybe more problems :)

Also, if you want something like twitter (yoursite.com/dynamicUserName), do the following in routes.rb :

```
resources :users, :path=>'' do
```

Comment: Thanks Marcel! it worked by adding to_parm method to the model.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good explanation from 2006 which looks good for Rails 2.3.*:
http://garrickvanburen.com/archive/using-names-in-rails-routes-instead-of-ids

The main problems I see is that you would want to ensure not only all of the above that Marcel mentiones, but that the name is unique.  ie put an index on name with `:unique => true` in the migration.

For rails3 to which I'm just now upgrading you would do the routing differently.  For example `map.connect` is replaced by `match`.